# Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function typpe

Tags: c++

```
//variables
bool GetSelectedSquare = 0;
bool UpdateBoard = 0;
bool isXTurn = true; 

uint8_t chosenSquare = GetSelectedSquare;     //some function that gets player's input 
UpdateBoard (chosenSquare), isXTurn ? 'X' : 'O'; //check if is X's turn, if not use O
isXTurn = !isXTurn;
```

I'm having an issue with the `UpdateBoard` line where in checking if its X's turn which is giving me the error in the title.

Comment: I'm not sure that is a valid conditional statement with the two operators preceding the '?'. Can you verify (or are you already certain) that work in c++?

Comment: What do you intend `UpdateBoard (chosenSquare)` to do? Just like the compiler, I think it looks a lot like a function call. It's just that `UpdateBoard` isn't a function.